# Azure Site Recovery Test Failover - No RDP

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I'm having an issue where failed-over servers through ASR do not allow for RDP on neither private nor public IP. The failover is successful and the VM starts up, but no connection. It doesn't seem as though any extensions get installed during the VM creation process.

I've have tried:

- Change size of VM
- Connect to different vNet during test failover
- define static IP in configuration
- create new public IP
- create and associate NSG
- disable/enable replication and re-replicate to Azure

I am also not able to ping from another Azure VM on the same vNet.

This is happening on several, but not all resources. I have other VMs that have tested successfully and I am able to connect to them.

Comment: Have you had a look at the boot diagnostics page to see if the machine is actually up?

Comment: I am glad it just isn't me. I am running into this same thing. Test failover won't let me rdp to the public IP, but I can to the private ip. If I do a real failover, no issue. I'll post a solution if I find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastiaan;

It is likely that you have a networking issue. You might recall that ASR prompted you for a VNET target to conduct the test-failover. Make sure the VNET is peered with another VNET from which you are testing access to. Check to make sure the test VM is associated with an NSG that permits traffic for RDP (best if done at the subnet level), and avoid having a public facing IP that is not filtered by an NSG. Note I do not recommend that you peer the VLAN with a production VNET, just to be safe.

We typically setup a jump host on its own VLAN with its own NSG that has the appropriate permissions to pass traffic to any host on the DR test VNET. We also peer the VNETs between the jump host and the test host. Best practice would be to setup the networking & NSGs, then build a test VM outside of the ASR process to ensure everything works, then do the test failover.

Here's a link to an instructional video I did on ASR. It does not discuss networking, but I am more than happy to answer any questions you may have. https://youtu.be/7XtnPyCb6Kc

Best of luck.

- Hank